# Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

Tags: networking, apt, server, updates, openstack

When trying `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

> Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
> Cannot initiate the connection to archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:67c:1360:8001::24). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)

I am getting this error, I tried all the methods that I found in different questions and none have worked for me. I do not know what else to do.

Comment: Are you on an IPv6 enabled network?  If not, then take a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9940/convince-apt-get-not-to-use-ipv6-method - I see this behavior when your system attempts IPv6 but you don't have an IPv6-capable networking

Answer (score 0):

I also tried a lot of solutions, but what finally did it for me, was disabling my antivirus.